# Unconventional odds ratio and 95% CI

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, odds-ratio

Using a generalized linear model; I got particularly large or small OR with 95% CI; while these are all insignificant as P > 0.05 for these, I just wanted to ask on the community if I am missing something?

Some of the strange values are as follows:

```
# Intercept OR:            3.913049e+08   2.5%: 2.776314e-29   97.5%: 2.034168e+266
# Some other values - OR:  1.861355e+07   2.5%: 1.308682e-21   97.5%: 6.239984e+199
```

Comment: Presumably the equivalent values for log-odds are simply the logarithms of those.   My guess is that you have multicollinearity across your explanatory variables with a tiny amount of precision noise and this is driving your reported results

Answer (score 1):

There are no numbers would immediately be obviously wrong.  The only possibility would be numbers that are mathematically impossible, such as odds ratios that are negative.  In general, regression coefficients are keyed to the units of your data, so you could make the coefficients arbitrarily large or small by converting, say, length data between nanometers and kilometers.

If there is some well grounded reason to believe that the variables 'should' be significant, there are a couple possibilities.  First, as @Henry [notes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609358/unconventional-odds-ratio-and-95-ci#comment1131130_609358), you could have multicollinearity.  You can check VIFs for this.  If you have it, you won't be able to get highly informative tests of individual variables, but you could get a simultaneous test of the collinear variables and show that something in there somewhere is related to the outcome.  With logistic regression (or ordinal, or multinomial), another possibility is that there is complete separation in your dataset.  You can simply use a different type of test, such as a likelihood ratio test or a score test.  You can also get CIs based on the likelihoods or score functions.  To learn more about those topics, try reading some of our threads categorized under the [multicollinearity](/questions/tagged/multicollinearity) and [separation](/questions/tagged/separation) tags (you may want to sort by 'votes' or 'frequent' and start reading down from the top).

Comment: Thank you for your response. There really is no strong reason to believe that the variables should be significant. I was just curious about such large odds ratios, what I’ve concluded is that these large OR, 95% CI are telling us pretty much nothing about the variables, let me know if you have any additional thoughts, thank you!

Comment: @BR27, without more context, it's impossible to say what they tell us.  Maybe they tell us something, maybe the units are weird, maybe it's range restriction on X, maybe it's small N, maybe it's separation or multcollinearity, or maybe it's some entirely different thing.

Comment: Thank you for your response!In the data, all of the values are categorical variables and not continuous.